# Remove focus from textbox - Sencha

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, textarea

I am having problem removing focus from textbox on sencha. There is a textareafield, user clicks on it to enter value after that i am not able remove focus from textareafield after this keyboard appears where ever it is clicked(on Screen). blur() seems to work in chrome but it does not work in iOS.

I looked onto [sencha forum also](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?158136-Remove-focus-from-textfield-on-Android).

Is there any solution to overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

We usually set focus to some other element to remove it from your element. But still there is [`blur` method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_blur.asp).

I tested this code, it works in Chrome

> myField.fieldEl.dom.blur();

Have a look at this [Sencha forum thread](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?105331-How-to-set-focus-for-textfield/page2) too. It seems this wouldn't work on iPad.

Comment: Have you tried Chrome in iOS? Maybe you could persuade users to use it in order to get a better experience (sounds weird, doesn't it?).